# How do I complete the 'The Madness Contained' achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

The Demon Hunter class achievement *The Madness Contained* requires you to "Spend 150 Hatred and 50 Discipline in 6 seconds."

Using the Vengeance passive ability, it's simple enough to *get* 150 Hatred and Preparation can instantly restore all Discipline and with the Invigoration Rune can add 10. Using a 14 discipline skill twice, Preparation with Invigoration and that same skill thrice more with a +2 discipline item equipped or fast Discipline regeneration or using the passive Perfectionist to bring he cost down to 12.6, would consume 50 discipline. Hatred is easy to burn in no time with 3 Cluster Arrows. There are many other examples where the math will work out to count up the costs.

The problem I'm having is the cooldowns are too long and/or the skill costs too low to do this in 6 seconds for Discipline skills. I feel like I'm missing something simple or I'm doing it wrong or maybe I'm just not good enough. In theory, if you had +20 discipline, you wouldn't need preparation and could just spam companion 5 times, but I've yet to see anything with that much of a Discipline boost.

**In what order should I use which skills in order to complete this achievement?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need for +discipline gear. I got it with Vengeance in my passive slot, then using smoke screen/shadow power, smoke screen/shadow power, preparation, cluster bomb x3, smoke screen/shadow power, smoke screen/shadow power,.

Also, it seems that **you can't get the achievement while in town.**

EDIT: Just got in Bastion's Keep using this method so can be done there. (patch 1.04)

Comment: This is the approach I used. It was simpler than seeking out +discipline gear, especially early on.

Comment: I did get the achievement while in town. Has this been changed recently?

Answer (score 5):

Equip vengeance passive skill to attain 150 hatred.  Equip (3) +6 discipline items to attain 48 discipline.  Equip preparation with punishment rune (spend 25 discipline to restore all hatred, no cooldown on preparation).  Cast preparation --> cluster arrow --> cluster arrow --> cluster arrow --> preparation in that order.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to to this is Vengeance (passive), Shadow Power, Vanish, Preparation (with + Discipline rune), Cluster arrow. Cast Vanish first, Shadow Power second, Preparation third, Shadow Power fourth, Vanish (again) fifth, then shoot Cluster Arrows three times.

If you use a fast 1-handed bow and spam the spells fast, it is easy to get. Vanish is cast first because it has a longer cool down. By the time you cast it again the cool down will have already been up.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably easiest with a specialized gearset. While +20 Discipline on one item is rare, there are mid-40's items with numbers over +5, so you should be able to easily equip a few. I'd recommend using Smoke Screen over Companion to spend Discipline, since it doesn't invoke a cool down on other abilities when used. Beyond that, equip a fast weapon, and maybe a few items with Increased Attack Speed affixes to increase the number of 'globals' available to you, and mash buttons like you've never mashed buttons before.

Comment: I guess a frenzy blessing would also help to get those spells out as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Multishot](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/multishot) to spend most of hatred quicky, [Shadowpower](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/shadow-power), [smokescreen](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/smoke-screen) and [vault](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/vault) or [caltrops](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/caltrops) for the discipline. You will need [perfectionist](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/passive/perfectionist), the rest depends on your items. Get a 1hand crossbows, they are usually faster than 2hand bows or crossbows.

Answer (score 0):

I unintendedly got this one by:

Spamming [Elemental Arrow (Ball Lightning)](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/elemental-arrow)
and [Smoke Screen (Lingering Fog)](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/smoke-screen) with a [Preparation](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/preparation) reset somewhere in between.

My attacks per second is at **1.55**.

Answer (score 0):

After using Vengeance as a passive and stacking Discipline adding gear to get 50 Discipline I used Cluster Arrow (50 hatred) and then spammed Companion as it has no real CD beyond attack speed.

My friend and I noticed, however, that you apparently MUST be in a single player game to get this. I did it while he'd gotten disconnected, then he tried for 15 minutes to get it in a game with me, and despite the fact that he was doing it all in around 3 seconds he was not getting the Achievement. He then made a new game and did it on his own and got it.

Comment: this achievement is "broken" when you change any skills you have to relog to fix it. when you relog the game with the spec you plan to use to do the achievement it will work just fine, that is why it worked for your friend first and you can do it in a group.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time trying to get this one. I only recently got it by pre-casting Preparation with the Focused Mind rune (which I had recently unlocked), 3x Cluster Arrow, 4x Smoke Screen, and got it on the first try. Previously, I was using Preparation in the middle to reset my Discipline, which apparently resets the achievement attempt.

Lesson learned: Don't use Preparation in the middle of your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Prep w/punishment rune methods for ever and could never get the achieve to work.  Switched to focused mind and got it on the first try.